# Wordpress user.php return error 500 on password check

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to make a connector that check if username and password match and then echo if username and password works:

```
<?php

    //$username = $_POST["user"];
    //$password = $_POST["password"];
    $username = 'existingusername'; //debug test
    $password = 'password'; // debug test

    include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/wp-includes/user.php");

    if (function_exists('wp_authenticate_username_password')) { 

        $auth = wp_authenticate_username_password(NULL, $username, $password);

        if (is_wp_error($auth)) 
        {
            echo 'Fail';
        } else {
            echo 'Success';
        }

    }else{

        echo 'Could not find wp_authenticate_username_password function<br>';
        echo dirname(__FILE__) . "/wp-includes/user.php";

    }

?>
```

I am using the function in file user.php and it is:

```
/**
 * Authenticate the user using the username and password.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 *
 * @param WP_User|WP_Error|null $user     WP_User or WP_Error object from a previous callback. Default null.
 * @param string                $username Username for authentication.
 * @param string                $password Password for authentication.
 * @return WP_User|WP_Error WP_User on success, WP_Error on failure.
 */
function wp_authenticate_username_password($user, $username, $password) {
    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        return $user;
    }

    if ( empty($username) || empty($password) ) {
        if ( is_wp_error( $user ) )
            return $user;

        $error = new WP_Error();

        if ( empty($username) )
            $error->add('empty_username', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The username field is empty.'));

        if ( empty($password) )
            $error->add('empty_password', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password field is empty.'));

        return $error;
    }

    $user = get_user_by('login', $username);

    if ( !$user )
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_username', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username. <a href="%s">Lost your password</a>?' ), wp_lostpassword_url() ) );

    /**
     * Filter whether the given user can be authenticated with the provided $password.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param WP_User|WP_Error $user     WP_User or WP_Error object if a previous
     *                                   callback failed authentication.
     * @param string           $password Password to check against the user.
     */
    $user = apply_filters( 'wp_authenticate_user', $user, $password );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
        return $user;

    if ( !wp_check_password($password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID) )
        return new WP_Error( 'incorrect_password', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password you entered for the username <strong>%1$s</strong> is incorrect. <a href="%2$s">Lost your password</a>?' ),
        $username, wp_lostpassword_url() ) );

    return $user;
}
```

It gives me an error 500 on the page. The other scripts that calls this (its an external server that listen if the echo is either Success or Fail).

I know the other script works as if I only do a php page that does echo 'Success'; it allows me to login.

Thanks

Comment: Look in your PHP error log for the actual error, not really possible to debug otherwise.